# Selenium IDE gives different result when running the same code

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium and was just playing with the IDE. I have a website that runs locally on my machine which has a IFrame and some popups. The following code runs very well when in medium speed mode or slow mode but fails when run in fast mode it gives an error (see line 15 below). Even though I tried to keep wait statements for things to sync.

Also notice that the same code is executed just fine in line 9 whether running slow or fast.

```
01    open          /default.aspx
02    type          id=loginContent_txtPassword xxxx
03    clickAndWait      id=loginContent_btnSet  
04    windowFocus       
05    click         //div[@id='lBar_leftItem_4']/a  
06    waitForFrameToLoad            aframe 30000
07    selectFrame               aframe  
08    click         css=img[title="Properties"] 
09    waitForPopUp      doc              30000
10    selectWindow      name=doc    
11    close     
12    selectWindow      null    
13    selectFrame               aframe  
14    click         css=img[title="Properties"] 
15    waitForPopUp      doc                        30000   ***[error] can't access dead object**
16    selectWindow      name=doc    
17    verifyText        id=popupContent_lblOwner           XYZ*
18    close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried many things... but finally putting a short pause (for a few seconds) before the statements that causes the issue solved the problem. Maybe the selenium requests are not synced and it sends some requests to the browser before it can handle it (just my guess!)